# Converting a HTML table full of images to look decent on mobile

Tags: html, css, image, mobile, html-table

I have a HTML table that's completely composed of eight images. They're puzzle pieces, so they have to be placed specifically and accurately.

This was easy on desktop, I just used absolute positioning to mess around with the pixels and make it work. It looks like trash on mobile though. The pieces are still together, but the puzzle is all the way to the right of the screen and it's too large. I've done a fair bit of Googling, but the only results I found were for tables composed of text, which doesn't work for my situation.

Here's the table, if anyone's interested -

```
<table width="100%" id="table" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td id="one">
                        <img src="1.png" class="merge0">
                    </td>
                    <td id="two">
                        <img id="2" src="6.png" class="merge">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="three">
                        <img src="4.png" class="row1">
                    </td>
                    <td id="four">
                        <img src="2.png" class="merge1">
                    </td>
                    <td id="five">
                        <img src="7.png" class="merge2">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="six">
                        <img src="8.png" class="row2">
                    </td>
                    <td id="seven">
                        <img src="5.png" class="row3">
                    </td>
                    <td id="eight">
                        <img src="3.png" class="row4">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

I read a bit about jQuery mobile, but I've never really grasped the concept of jQuery, and mobile is a foreign platform to me. I'm hoping to learn though :)

I've also tried those "desktop to mobile" converters, and they all are horrible.

Edit - I think people might suggest that I completely take the table out and use a different method of arranging my images. I'm really not sure how to go about doing this, and I'd prefer it if I could keep my current setup. If it's not possible though, I'd appreciate some pointers on how to do it differently.

Comment: You should completely take out the table and use CSS to redesign your entire page. Learning CSS is easy, basic CSS can be learned in about an hour or two if you're really committed. With CSS you can build pages that look good on any device or build mobile and desktop versions of the same site.

Comment: Oh alright. Sucks about the table though.. spent too much time on that. Could you point me in the right direction if I want to get this specific task done?

Comment: You need a basic knowledge of CSS first. I like codecademy (http://www.codecademy.com/courses/css-coding-with-style/0/1) After that it's just a matter of positioning your elements to match the table. You can keep the table if you use a mobile redirect. If you're site is "theturkey.com" your mobile site could be "m.theturkey.com"  here's a short Javascript you could plug in get that going ("http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/redirects/mobile-redirect"). Web design is a trial and error process, I don't know any specific resource to help you convert a table to CSS. It's easy though.

Answer (score 0):

Go over the [getting started page](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/about/getting-started.html) and then use [jQuery-mobile grids](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/content/content-grids.html):

```
<div class="ui-grid-a">
  <div class="ui-block-a"><img src="1.png" class="merge0"></div>
  <div class="ui-block-b"><img id="2" src="6.png" class="merge"></div>
</div>
```

For the grid with three images just use "ui-grid-b"

Hope this helps

best

M

Comment: Okay. So with two images, it's "ui-grid-a" and for three, it's "ui-grid-b"?

And this should look better on a mobile, correct? Thanks for the awesome reply!

Comment: yes jquery-mobile is a jquery framework - so don't forget to include the jquery-mobile.css and jquery.js as described on the "getting started page" there is kind of a template page which you can use - for testing you can also use JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yr2r1os7/ - best M